# RabbitMQ - How to Dead-letter / Process Messages in Expired Queues?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an a queue that has `x-expires` set. The issue I am having is that I need to do further processing on the messages that are in the queue ***IF*** the queue expires. My initial idea was to set `x-dead-letter-exchange` on the queue. But, when the queue expires, the messages just vanish without making it to the dead-letter exchange.

How can I dead-letter, or otherwise process, messages that are in a queue that expires?

Comment: You can't, at least not according to the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html): *"..expiration of a queue will not dead letter the messages in it."*

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you cannot do this by relying only on the `x-expire` feature. But a solution that worked in a similar case I had was to:

1. Use `x-message-ttl` to make sure messages die if not consumed in a timely manner,
2. Assign a dead letter exchange to the queue where all those messages will be routed,
3. Use `x-expires` to set the queue expiration to a value higher than the TTL of the messages,
4. (and this is the tricky part) Assuming you have control over your consumers, before the last consumer goes offline, delete the binding to your "dying" queue, potentially through a [REST API call](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) - this will prevent new messages from being routed to the queue.

This way the messages that were published before the last consumer died were already processed, existing messages will be dead-lettered before the queue expires, and new messages cannot come into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new dead letter queue that is bound to your dead letter exchange with the binding routing key set as the original queue name. In this way all expired messages sent to the dead letter exchange are routed to the dead letter queue.

Comment: I have not forgotten about your answer. I have not had the time to try it yet. Once I do, I will either mark it correct or comment.

Comment: `x-expires` sets the inactivity time which will trigger the deletion of the **queue**, not the TTL for the messages in it. So I believe the mechanism explained in this answer does not work in this case.